# Почему не закрывается диалоговое окно?

Tags: vuex, vuetify

Я пытаюсь добавить новый элемент в таблицу и закрыть диалоговое окно.
В файле компонента:

```html
<v-dialog
v-model="dialog"
max-width="500px">
  <v-btn
    color="blue darken-1"
    text
    @click="saveNewItem(curItem)">
    Save
  </v-btn>
</v-dialog>
```

```
import Vuex, { mapState, mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
computed: {
      ...mapState([
        'dialog',
      ]),
}
methods: {
      ...mapActions([
        'saveNewItem',
      ]),
}
```

В файле store.js:

```js
state: {
    dialog: false,
    }
mutations: {
    saveItem: (state, payload) => {
      if (state.editedIndex > -1) {
        Object.assign(state.desserts[state.editedIndex], payload)
      } else {
        state.desserts.push(payload)
      }
      state.dialog = false
    },
}
actions: {
    saveNewItem: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit('saveItem', payload)
    },
}
```

при клике новый элемент добавляется в таблицу, но диалоговое окно не закрывается.
что не так?